# How do I convert a PNG string into a Numpy array?

Tags: python, image, numpy

I need to convert a `PNG` image string into a `numpy` array. What are the best approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib` for that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

array = plt.imread('my_picture.png')
```

or `PIL`:

```
from PIL import image
import numpy as np

array = np.array(Image.open('my_picture.png'))
```

or `cv2`:

```
array = cv2.imread('my_picture.png')
```

or `imageio`:

```
import imageio
im = imageio.imread('my_picture.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Tha question asked how to convert a PNG string into a numpy.ndarray, instead of how to read image from file system.

So the input should be a based 64 encoded string.

The best way is then to use

```
np.frombuffer(data, np.uint8)
```